Is there ever a reason to use generators rather than promise-based async code?
I know that generators paired with iterators can be used to write async code, but what’s the benefit of using it? I’ve heard it offers more fine grained control than promises, but so far I haven’t seen a case of that… I also believe I’m right in saying that while generators where considered for the implementation of async/await, all JS engines use promises to implement it. Here’s an example of using generators to handle async operations:
function fetchData() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // Generator function
    function* fetchGenerator() {
      try {
        console.log("Fetching data...");
        const data1 = yield fetch('https://api.example.com/data1');
        console.log("Data 1 fetched");
        const data2 = yield fetch('https://api.example.com/data2');
        console.log("Data 2 fetched");
        resolve({ data1, data2 });
      } catch (error) {
        reject(error);
      }
    }
    
    // Create generator iterator
    const generator = fetchGenerator();
    
    // Function to handle generator iteration
    function handleAsync(generator, yieldedValue) {
      const { value, done } = generator.next(yieldedValue);
      if (done) {
        resolve(value);
      } else {
        Promise.resolve(value)
          .then(
            result => handleAsync(generator, result),
            error => generator.throw(error)
          );
      }
    }
    
    handleAsync(generator);
  });
}

fetchData().then(result => {
  console.log("All data fetched:", result);
}).catch(error => {
  console.error(“Fetching data:", error);
});


If handleAsync looks for the done flag, shouldn't the generator function return its result instead of calling resolve itself?

Generators on their own do not make code run asynchronously. In your example you introduce asynchrony by creating promises. So as I see it, your code is not an example of "rather then promise-based".

Generators can be used for what other languages have the concept of Ranges for! ... e.g. ... https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Range.html ... Generators are just more versatile/generic.

I usually use generators to create iterators to iterate something. Some scenario would be to iterate some paged data, I find it very convenient, if you can write simpler / more convenient code without generators, you better do. So it depends.
Basically generators in async code means usually async generators + for await.


.as-console-wrapper{max-height: 100% !important}
<script type="module">

const fetch = url => new Promise(r => console.log('fetching', url) ?? setTimeout(() => r(Math.random()), 500));

async function* fetchPages(pages) {
  for(let i = 1; i <= pages; i++){
    const num = await fetch('https://api.example.com/data' + i);
    yield {num};
  }
}

for await(const data of fetchPages(10)){
  console.log('data', JSON.stringify(data));
  // do something with data
  if(data.num < await .3){ // some async code inside for await
    console.log('found condition, breaking');
    break;
  }
}

</script>



An interesting scenario is to wrap Promice.race() into an async generator for more convenient race handling:


<script type="module">

const fetch = url => new Promise(r => console.log('fetching', url) ?? setTimeout(() => r(Math.random()), Math.random() * 1000));

async function* fetchPages(pages) {
  const promises = Array.from({length:pages},  (_, i) => {
    const out = fetch('https://api.example.com/data' + (i + 1));
    out.then(() => promises.splice(promises.indexOf(out), 1));
    return out;
  });
  while(promises.length) yield {num: await Promise.race(promises)};
}

for await(const data of fetchPages(10)){
  console.log('data', JSON.stringify(data));
  // do something with data
  if(data.num < await .3){ // some async code inside for await
    console.log('found condition, breaking');
    break;
  }
}

</script>



There's also new Array.fromAsync to create arrays for example from async generators.


.as-console-wrapper{max-height: 100% !important}
<script type="module">

const fetch = url => new Promise(r => console.log('fetching', url) ?? setTimeout(() => r(Math.random()), 500));

async function* fetchPages(pages) {
  for(let i = 1; i <= pages; i++){
    const num = await fetch('https://api.example.com/data' + i);
    yield {num};
  }
}

console.log(await Array.fromAsync(fetchPages(3)));

</script>




@MattStyles break breaks the generator, the fetches that follow are from Array#fromAsync, i should split the code into 2 snippets to avoid confusion

Makes sense, I’ve deleted my comment to avoid confusion

@MattStyles added Promise.race() handling

I used it once in a personal project to handle pagination:
GitHub
    async function* getSubredditIterator<TGetSubredditArgs extends GetSubredditArgs>(
        args: TGetSubredditArgs
    ): AsyncIterator<GetSubredditResponse<TGetSubredditArgs>> {
        let after: string | null = null

        while (true) {
            const res: GetSubredditResponse<TGetSubredditArgs> = await getSubreddit({
                after,
                ...args,
            })

            after = res.data.after

            yield res
        }
    }


Consumer:
const memeSubredditIterator = reddit.getSubredditIterator({
    name: "meme",
    sortMethod: SortingMethod.New,
    limit: 5,
})

const memeResults0To4 = await memeSubredditIterator.next()
const memeResults5To9 = await memeSubredditIterator.next()

In my case, I would say that the benefit was not having to handle the pagination by the consumer.
Otherwise, he would add to save the "after" himself between each request.

Regarding the first part of the OP's question(s) ...

I know that generators paired with iterators can be used to write async code, but what’s the benefit of using it? I’ve heard it offers more fine grained control than promises, but so far I haven’t seen a case of that ...

What the OP is looking for are async generators and async generator functions. They come in handy when one has to deal with a sequence of async tasks.
A personal short list of recently answered question which are related to exactly this matter ...

"How to use setTimeout in order to achieve both typewriter effects sequently, printing a line character by delayed character and line by delayed line?"

"How to schedule the execution of broadcast tasks from a queue of to be broadcasted data with a one second delay in between each broadcast invocation?"

"Best way to perform multiple time taking operations for every single item in a large array"




And regarding my direct comment at the OP's question (far above) ...

Generators can be used for what other languages have the concept of Ranges for! ... e.g. ... https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Range.html ... Generators are just more versatile/generic.

... the by far biggest advantage of generators, regardless of async or non async ones, is, that they can yield real computed values like one gets for instance from ranges.
One/some possible implementation/s could look similar to the following provided example code ...


// spread syntax applied on a range type invokes its iterator.
const simple_zero_to_three_sequence = [...(0).to(3)]; 
const minus4_toPlus8_stepPlus3_sequence = [...(-4).to(8).step(3)];
const plus11_toMinus5_stepMinus4_sequence = [...(11).to(-5).step(-4)];

console.log({
  simple_zero_to_three_sequence,
  minus4_toPlus8_stepPlus3_sequence,
  plus11_toMinus5_stepMinus4_sequence,
});
console.log('\n');


// const failingRangeType = new SafeIntegerRange(0, 3, null);
const simple_zero_to_three_range = new SafeIntegerRange(0, 3);

// const simple_zero_to_three_range = (0).to(3);
const minus7_toPlus2_stepPlus2_range = (-7).to(2).step(2);
const plus5_toMinus9_stepMinus3_range = (5).to(-9).step(-3);

console.log('simple_zero_to_three_range.next() ...', simple_zero_to_three_range.next());
console.log('simple_zero_to_three_range.next() ...', simple_zero_to_three_range.next());
console.log('simple_zero_to_three_range.next() ...', simple_zero_to_three_range.next());
console.log('simple_zero_to_three_range.next() ...', simple_zero_to_three_range.next());
console.log('simple_zero_to_three_range.next() ...', simple_zero_to_three_range.next());
console.log('\n');

console.log('minus7_toPlus2_stepPlus2_range.next() ...', minus7_toPlus2_stepPlus2_range.next());
console.log('minus7_toPlus2_stepPlus2_range.next() ...', minus7_toPlus2_stepPlus2_range.next());
console.log('minus7_toPlus2_stepPlus2_range.next() ...', minus7_toPlus2_stepPlus2_range.next());
console.log('minus7_toPlus2_stepPlus2_range.next() ...', minus7_toPlus2_stepPlus2_range.next());
console.log('minus7_toPlus2_stepPlus2_range.next() ...', minus7_toPlus2_stepPlus2_range.next());
console.log('minus7_toPlus2_stepPlus2_range.next() ...', minus7_toPlus2_stepPlus2_range.next());
console.log('\n');

console.log('plus5_toMinus9_stepMinus3_range.next() ...', plus5_toMinus9_stepMinus3_range.next());
console.log('plus5_toMinus9_stepMinus3_range.next() ...', plus5_toMinus9_stepMinus3_range.next());
console.log('plus5_toMinus9_stepMinus3_range.next() ...', plus5_toMinus9_stepMinus3_range.next());
console.log('plus5_toMinus9_stepMinus3_range.next() ...', plus5_toMinus9_stepMinus3_range.next());
console.log('plus5_toMinus9_stepMinus3_range.next() ...', plus5_toMinus9_stepMinus3_range.next());
console.log('plus5_toMinus9_stepMinus3_range.next() ...', plus5_toMinus9_stepMinus3_range.next());
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
<script>
function parseSafeInteger(value) {
  const int = parseInt(value, 10);

  if (!Number.isSafeInteger(int)) {
    throw new TypeError('The provided value needs to be parsable into a safe integer value.')
  }
  return int;
}

function* createSafeIntegerRangeGenerator(current, end, step) {

  yield current;

  if ((current < end) && (step >= 1)) {
    while (
      ((current = current + step) <= end) &&
      Number.isSafeInteger(current)
    ) {
      yield current;
    }
  } else if ((current > end) && (step <= -1)) {
    while (
      ((current = current + step) >= end) &&
      Number.isSafeInteger(current)
    ) {
      yield current;
    }
  }
}
class SafeIntegerRange {
  #generator;

  #begin;
  #end;
  #step;

  constructor(...args) {
    const [begin, end, step] = args;

    this.#begin = parseSafeInteger(begin);
    this.#end = parseSafeInteger(end);

    this.#step = (args.length >= 3)
      ? parseSafeInteger(step)
      : Number.NaN;

  }

  step(value) {
    if (Number.isSafeInteger(this.#step)) {
      // property already initialized (one time initialization only).
      return this.#step;
    }
    this.#step = parseSafeInteger(value);

    return this;
  }
  next(value) {
    if (!this.#generator) {
      if (!Number.isSafeInteger(this.#step)) {
        // default.
        this.#step = 1;
      }
      this.#generator = createSafeIntegerRangeGenerator(
        this.#begin, this.#end, this.#step,
      );
    }
    return this.#generator.next();
  }

  [Symbol.iterator]() {
    if (!Number.isSafeInteger(this.#step)) {
      // default.
      this.#step = 1;
    }
    return createSafeIntegerRangeGenerator(
      this.#begin, this.#end, this.#step,
    );
  }
}

function upToInteger(value) {
  const begin = parseSafeInteger(this);
  const end = parseSafeInteger(value);

  return new SafeIntegerRange(begin, end);
}
Reflect.defineProperty(Number.prototype, 'to', {
  value: upToInteger,
});
</script>



